# JWST team have delayed opening the sunshield, all future deployments listed at TBD on the where is webb website. Time to panic?

Tags: james-webb-telescope

They have delayed the sunshield deployment and I hope its not a problem, but does anyone have any information as to what the current status of the mission is?

Comment: *Welcome to Stack Exchange!* It's best if you include a link to what you've read so far. That way answer authors will have an idea which source(s) of information you are using and which ones you'll benefit from finding out about; there are so many of them. *Thanks!*

Comment: No need for panic yet, the *main* thing that has happened is that friday's activities did not complete quite on schedule, then the team did the NewYear loafing thing that humans are prone to. So then are now completing that sequence before continuing. The original deployment schedule seems to have considered only science/engineering aspects, not human social nature.

Comment: https://scitechdaily.com/nasa-moves-forward-with-webb-space-telescope-sunshield-tensioning/    The Webb mission operations team began the first steps in the process of tensioning the first layer of Webb’s sunshield this morning around 10 a.m. EST.

It will take the team two to three days to tension the five-layer sunshield. The plan for today is to focus on the first layer, the largest and the one closest to the Sun.

Comment: https://jwst.nasa.gov/content/webbLaunch/whereIsWebb.html has nice real-time updates on the status

Comment: The downvotes are not needed. This is a new member, so please be nice. People new to space exploration don't understand that things going semi-awry is standard operating procedure. Spacecraft are very complex devices. Something always goes semi-awry. That doesn't mean it's time to panic.

Answer (score 11):

> Time to panic?

No.

> All future deployments listed at TBD on the where is webb website.

NASA has said upfront that except for a small number of time-critical activities that the Webb deployment timetable is flexible, by design. This was one of those. Apparently a sensor or two failed early in the deployment of the sunshield. From https://blogs.nasa.gov/webb/2021/12/31/first-of-two-sunshield-mid-booms-deploys/,

> Switches that should have indicated that the cover rolled up did not trigger when they were supposed to. However, secondary and tertiary sources offered confirmation that it had. Temperature data seemed to show that the sunshield cover unrolled to block sunlight from a sensor, and gyroscope sensors indicated motion consistent with the sunshield cover release devices being activated.

The JWST team took time to analyze the issue and eventually moved along. The deployment and tensioning of the sunshield is proceeding. What the JWST team is most worried about are the many single points of failure in the deployment. Sensor failures are not single points of failure and in fact are things to be expected.

Think of your car. How many false alarms do you get? My vehicle regularly complains that the gas tank cap is ajar. It is not. It's just a goofy sensor that sometimes gives false readings. Unlike the JWST, my vehicle only has one sensor for this problem. The JWST is outfitted with secondary and tertiary sensors just in case a sensor fails.

Comment: A common occurrence in satellite troubleshooting is that you can't put everything in telemetry, so you have to predict pre-launch which data will be most critical. Sometimes, you discover you'd rather have something else instead, but you're stuck with it.  It's like the story about a bunch of people trying to identify an elephant by touch alone: each sensor gives you one small piece of the puzzle, but you'll never have all the pieces, so it takes slow, careful, effort to figure out what the rest of the picture must be, and minimize the chance of doing the wrong thing from misunderstanding.

Comment: Also: they’ve just finished sheet number 5, so all is good.

Comment: @Ludo As I replied to "time to panic", the answer is no.